How to check if WindowsPath is_absolute() if path is provided in posix format (ie '/windows/')
I have a CLI that is suppose to accept absolute paths but not relative paths.  I set up my promp_toolkit PathCompleter to only complete absolute paths, only to be surprised that it would allow me to use posix strings to resolve windows directories.  So for example if I want something in C:\Windows I can put /windows and it will understand I'm referring to the C: and autocomplete correctly.  An odd but potentially mildly useful feature.
Only problem is that when I call is_absolute() on the a WindowsPath of '/windows' it returns False, despite it effectively referring to an absolute path.  So now I have an autocompleter that will complete a string that my argparser then complains about, not so good.
Is there a way to determine that the posix format string is still refering to an absolute Windows path so I can manage to not barf on these sort of paths?  If not I'll have to figure out some way to keep autocompleter from suggesting them.
